# DTExec: How to use a semicolon within a parameter value for SSIS package

Tags: parameters, ssis, dtexec

I just learned from [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899054/ssis-package-stuck-at-created-execution-status) that if parameters are not configured correctly (if you are missing a required parameter) when using DTExec to run a package from the command line, your package will forever be stuck in a "Created Execution" status, and never actually run.

Some similar odd behavior is occurring when I have a semicolon *within* my SSIS package parameter when using DTExec. If there is a semicolon in a parameter, DTExec simply says:

> "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

```
DTExec.exe /ISSERVER "\SSISDB\Data Feeds\Data Feed Project\Data Feed.dtsx" /SERVER "." /parameter RequiredParameter(string);parameter;value;has;semicolons
```

What is the correct syntax? Escaping the semicolons does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer courtesy of [this SQL Server Central post](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic851583-148-1.aspx). The command line argument for the parameter name/type/value must be quoted, and then within the argument, the parameter value must be double quoted:

```
/parameter "RequiredParameter(string);""parameter;value;has;semicolons"""
```

The whole execution command line from the example above becomes:

```
DTExec.exe /ISSERVER "\SSISDB\Data Feeds\Data Feed Project\Data Feed.dtsx" /SERVER "." /parameter "RequiredParameter(string);""parameter;value;has;semicolons"""
```